# Envoy and Mysql

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-envoy

I'm making a SSH Task with Envoy and Laravel, the problem is that when I make something like

```
@task('truncate', ['on' => 'remote'])
    echo 'Truncating table...'
    mysql --help
@endtask
```

It outputs

```
mysql: command not found
```

And yes... I have mysql installed on remote server. If I manually ssh into it and write mysql it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In remote server I'm using Zsh and Envoy is using Bash, thats why mysql isnt been loaded with PATH.